# Files manipulations on C: Binary files

Tags: c, file, binary

I need to write a program which gets 4 arguments, the first one a string represents a binary file divided to bytes, and the second, third, and fourth (x,y,z) are 3 integers where their sum is 8. each byte has x left bits, y bits after them, and finally z bits. each group represent a number.

I need to print these numbers. For example for `x=4, y=3, z=1` and file has 3 bytes:

**1010 0001 1 0101 011 1 0010 001 1** the result would be 10 0 1 5 3 1 2 1 1.

I'd like your help with files in C. This is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define  SEEK_SET   0

#define  SEEK_CUR   1

#define  SEEK_END   2

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc!=5) {
        printf("enter a file name and 3 integers such that their sum is 8");
        return 0;
    } else {
        FILE* f;
        f=fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (f==NULL) {
            printf("File %s does not exists \n", argv[1]);
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            int length=0;
            int offset=0;
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            length=ftell(f);
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

            while (offset < length) {
                int i;
                double sum=0;
                for (i=1; i<= atoi(argv[2]); ++i) {
                    double exponent= atoi(argv[1])- i;
                    sum=getc(f)*pow(2, exponent); 

                }
                printf("%d ", (int)sum);
                sum=0;

                for (i=1; i<= atoi(argv[3]); ++i) {
                    double exponent= atoi(argv[1])- i;
                    sum=fetc(f)*pow(2, exponent);
                }
                printf("%d ", (int)sum);
                sum=0;
                for (i=1; i<= atoi(argv[4]); ++i) {
                    double exponent= atoi(argv[1])- i;
                    sum=getc(f)*pow(2, exponent);
                }
                printf("%d ", (int)sum);
                offset+=8;
            }
            fclose(f);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Couple of questions:

1. I copy the whole `argc, **argv` from other program which use files. is this Ok? I mean when I enter `main c:\stackExchange 5 2 1` would it automatically give 4 to `argc`  and an array of the other parameters as strings? I assumed it does, and wrote the above.
2. I assumed that `getc(f)` returns a bit, is this correct?

any other corrections would be gladly welcome.

Comment: Remember that `argv[0]` is the name of the program, not the actual first argument which is `argv[1]`. You try to `fopen` `argv[0]`.

Comment: Do not `#define SEEK_SET` et al; they are defined for you in `<stdio.h>` (and may not have the values you show, though the preprocessor would probably complain if there was a mismatch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, `argc` is the number of entries in the `argv` array, i.e. the number of arguments plus one. So for your example command line `argc` would be 5, with `argv` containing this:

```
argv[0] : "main"
argv[1] : "c:\\stackExchange"
argv[2] : "5"
argv[3] : "2"
argv[4] : "1"
argv[5] : NULL
```

Regarding your second question, `getc` returns an integer, which if it's not `EOF` can be interpreted as a character or a byte depending on if you read text or binary data.

Comment: Shouldn't I just use fgetc instead? do they both promote the buffer?

Comment: Cpluplus says: "fgetc and getc are equivalent, except that the latter one may be implemented as a macro", what does that mean? as a marco?

Comment: @Numerator The use of `getc` is actually deprecated in favor of `fgetc` so I would recommend it.

Comment: @Numerator A macro is what is created by using the pre processor `#define` keyword, and that means the argument to `getc` may be evaluated more than once which might be bad.

Comment: Also, `argv[argc] == 0`; there is a null pointer at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

getc/fgetc returns a byte(=8bits), not a bit.

try this in your main While, for each byte in the file:

```
char b = fgetc(f); 
printf("%d %d %d ", b>>(y+z), (b<<x)>>(x+z), b<<(x+y)>>(x+y) );
```

Comment: Good answer, you need to make that last one as `(b<<(x+y))>>(x+y)`

Comment: @Andy :Where exactly should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

An additional (more cosmetic) suggestion: under unix/linux the convention is, that zero is returned for success of the main program only, but this is no bad idea for dos/windows either. In case of usage hints often 1 is returned, while real errors, like not finding the file may lead to an exit code of 2 or greater. This eases a consistent handling in shell scripts or batches.